# hidding div overflow contents

Tags: html, css

i have issue hiding overflow contents / div (#map_Marker_Check_Block) inside another div. The parent div position nearly mid of screen. The div "map_Marker_Check_Block" is position to right -12em. so when user click this div, jquery plays animation and slide whole div to position right 0. the functional part is working fine, is just have issue of hiding #map_Marker_Check_Block div (15em-12em). note because i need y-scrolbar to see contents in hidden div contents also.

html

```
<div id="map_Marker_Check_Block">
<div class="markerDiv" id="maker_school">
    <label class="marker_label">School</label> <input class=
    "marker_ckeckbox" name="markerType" type="checkbox" value="school">
</div><br>

<div class="markerDiv" id="maker_gym">
    <label class="marker_label">Gym</label> <input class="marker_ckeckbox"
    name="markerType" type="checkbox" value="gym">
</div><br>
</div>
```

css

```
#sp_tab2 {
position:relative;
}

#map_Marker_Check_Block {
display:block;
position:absolute;
width:15em;
height:400px;
top:0;
right:-12em;
z-index:10;  
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ahhh!! late night work and this is what happened, my fault. i miss overflow: hidden property in parent tab.

```
#sp_tab2 {
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
}
```